# upgrade mariadb10.1.26 to 1.3

Tags: mariadb, debian-stretch

when I want to install maria db it wrote :
mariadb-server : Dépend: mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.7+maria~stretch) it not will be not installed

also I use a software and it write :
You are running MySQL version 5.5.5-10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1. While this version is compatible, future releases of our software will require version 5.6.2

I need help to finish this upgrade.

Thank you.

Comment: The version numbers do not make sense; please check them.

Comment: The safest way to do it is to take a full backup of your databases and then remove-purge your actual install of mariadb and then perform an upgrade of your system and then install the neweste version of mariadb.